# Save Generated GameObject as Prefab

Tags: unity, unityscript

I've written a script which will automatically generate a Mesh, assign a MeshFilter, MeshRenderer, BoxCollider, and RigidBody.

This script is meant as a tool to rapidly create a certain class of objects (in this case, dice). I don't want them to actually generate at runtime.

Is there a way to convert the GameObject to a Prefab with all of its different generated properties so that I can simply drop them into my game?

Just trying to drag it into the Assets causes it to lose its Mesh. Also to note, I have it so I can generate the Mesh via the Inspector in a ContextMenu, which works well.

Comment: You should check this method from PrefabUtility's class: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.CreatePrefab.html .Just take note that this is a UnityEditor's namespace class, so don't put it in a class that would be compiled in your builds or use platform dependent compilation blocks.

Comment: Thanks. I think I ended up figuring it out by first saving the generated mesh as an asset, then saving the object itself as a prefab. I'll check out that code though, maybe it'll have something nicer or more clever than what I'm doing.

Comment: @samanime please feel free to share your solution as an answer to guide future users.

Comment: Once I have a solid solution, I certainly will. I think I'm about 90% of the way to something I like. This is for a side project, so it'll take a bit. ;)

Comment: @samanime how did you save the asset? Which asset? The mesh? Or did you use something like formating it to fbx or obj?